# How to set DataTemplate width to the width of the Listbox?

Tags: wpf

Here's the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.containerstyle.aspx).

```
<GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Expander IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" 
                      BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
              <Expander.Header>
                <DockPanel>
                  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                             Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                </DockPanel>
              </Expander.Header>
              <Expander.Content>
                <ItemsPresenter />
              </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

How can I make it occupy the whole width of the listbox? (HorizontalScrollBar is disabled)?
What I exactly need is DockPanel to be streched.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the reference of PresentationFramework.Aero in your project.
After this in your ListBox you have to insert this attribute:

```
<ListBox 
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Whell, real broblem as it happened was not with listbox but the expander's header. =( http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/02/24/stretching-content-in-an-expander-header/